# How to Add Proguard in Library Module in Android

Tags: android, build.gradle, proguard

**I want to add proguard rule in library module.**

Answer (score 1):

**There are 2 ways to add proguard rules in library module**

- Remove enable proguard line from library gradle and add library proguard rules in **App Proguard**.
- if there is need to add proguard rules in Library module.
  then we have to use **consumerProguardFiles** inplace of **proguardFiles**.

use code like below.

```
release {
            minifyEnabled false
            consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```